# Is an '!'-symbol in an XML attribute name allowed?

Tags: xml

I'm dealing with incoming XML-messages from an external party, so they're not authored by myself. I believe they aren't using valid XML-syntax.

Consider the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyItems>
    <MyItem !myAttributeName=""/> 
    <!--    ^ Note the '!'-mark at the beginning of 'myAttributeName'.-->
</MyItems>
```

I'm surprised to encounter an exclamation mark at the beginning of an XML-attribute. **Is this blatantly invalid XML? Or am I missing something here?** Basically all XML-parsers and validation tools are incapable of dealing with this attribute name, but I'm still surprised that this is being used in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this blatantly invalid XML?

Yes.

Valid names are composed thus:

```
NameStartChar   ::=         ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
                            [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] |
                            [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] |
                            [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]

NameChar        ::=         NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] |
                            [#x203F-#x2040]

Name            ::=         NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```

`!` is `#x21` so not only is it not allowed at the start of an XML name, it's not allowed anywhere within one, either. In XML terms, what you have there is gibberish.

Comment: Good answer (+1), but also note difference between [***Well-formed vs Valid XML***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)

Comment: @kjhughes yes, in this case it's not well-formed and hence also not valid (nothing that isn't well-formed can be valid). When something's this far off well-formed I prefer *gibberish* unless I've a need to be particularly precise in my terminology. In "valid names" above I'm using *valid* in the general meaning rather than the XML-specific one.

Answer (score 1):

All symbols that differ from `_` or `:` at in an attribute name are unexpected tokens for all XML validation tools.

As I could see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn), the syntax that XML allows is :

```
Extender ::= #x00B7 | #x02D0 | #x02D1 | #x0387 | #x0640 | #x0E46
| #x0EC6 | #x3005 | [#x3031-#x3035] | [#x309D-#x309E] | [#x30FC-#x30FE]

CombiningChar ::= [#x0300-#x0345] | [#x0360-#x0361] | [#x0483-#x0486] | [#x0591-#x05A1] | [#x05A3-#x05B9] | [#x05BB-#x05BD] | #x05BF | [#x05C1-#x05C2] | #x05C4 | [#x064B-#x0652] | #x0670 | [#x06D6-#x06DC] | [#x06DD-#x06DF] | [#x06E0-#x06E4] | [#x06E7-#x06E8] | [#x06EA-#x06ED] | [#x0901-#x0903] | #x093C | [#x093E-#x094C] | #x094D | [#x0951-#x0954] | [#x0962-#x0963] | [#x0981-#x0983] | #x09BC | #x09BE | #x09BF | [#x09C0-#x09C4] | [#x09C7-#x09C8] | [#x09CB-#x09CD] | #x09D7 | [#x09E2-#x09E3] | #x0A02 | #x0A3C | #x0A3E | #x0A3F | [#x0A40-#x0A42] | [#x0A47-#x0A48] | [#x0A4B-#x0A4D] | [#x0A70-#x0A71] | [#x0A81-#x0A83] | #x0ABC | [#x0ABE-#x0AC5] | [#x0AC7-#x0AC9] | [#x0ACB-#x0ACD] | [#x0B01-#x0B03] | #x0B3C | [#x0B3E-#x0B43] | [#x0B47-#x0B48] | [#x0B4B-#x0B4D] | [#x0B56-#x0B57] | [#x0B82-#x0B83] | [#x0BBE-#x0BC2] | [#x0BC6-#x0BC8] | [#x0BCA-#x0BCD] | #x0BD7 | [#x0C01-#x0C03] | [#x0C3E-#x0C44] | [#x0C46-#x0C48] | [#x0C4A-#x0C4D] | [#x0C55-#x0C56] | [#x0C82-#x0C83] | [#x0CBE-#x0CC4] | [#x0CC6-#x0CC8] | [#x0CCA-#x0CCD] | [#x0CD5-#x0CD6] | [#x0D02-#x0D03] | [#x0D3E-#x0D43] | [#x0D46-#x0D48] | [#x0D4A-#x0D4D] | #x0D57 | #x0E31 | [#x0E34-#x0E3A] | [#x0E47-#x0E4E] | #x0EB1 | [#x0EB4-#x0EB9] | [#x0EBB-#x0EBC] | [#x0EC8-#x0ECD] | [#x0F18-#x0F19] | #x0F35 | #x0F37 | #x0F39 | #x0F3E | #x0F3F | [#x0F71-#x0F84] | [#x0F86-#x0F8B] | [#x0F90-#x0F95] | #x0F97 | [#x0F99-#x0FAD] | [#x0FB1-#x0FB7] | #x0FB9 | [#x20D0-#x20DC] | #x20E1 | [#x302A-#x302F] | #x3099 | #x309A

NameChar ::=  Letter | Digit | '.' | '-' | '_' | ':' | CombiningChar | Extender

Name ::=  (Letter | '_' | ':') (NameChar)*
```

**Attribute ::= Name Eq AttValue**

**AttValue ::= '"' ([^<&"] | Reference)* '"' |
    "'" ([^<&'] | Reference)* "'"**

These are all EBNF that XML allows, and that is why an attribute with `!` symbol in name isn't well-formed.